# Wrongly sudo apt-get remove gtk2.0

Tags: sudo, gtk2

I used `sudo apt-get remove gtk2.0` command wrongly. Now, I don't know how to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk2.0` isn’t the full name of a single package, so `apt-get remove gtk2.0` would have offered to remove all packages whose name contains `gtk2.0`, and any packages depending on them. To fix this removal, you’ll need to find the packages which were removed.

If you look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` (`less /var/log/apt/history.log`), you should find a set of lines containing

```
Commandline: apt-get remove gtk2.0
```

Followed by a line starting with

```
Remove:
```

This line will list all the packages which were removed. Ignoring the parentheses (`()`) and commas, convert this list into an installation command:

```
sudo apt-get install ...
```

Once that completes, your system should be back in the state it was in before (apart from the indicators signalling that packages were automatically installed, but that doesn’t matter too much).